# Solving a system of equations with an unknown constant

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

How do I find all values of: $$ a \in R $$ for the system of equations below?

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_2-3x_3+2x_4=1 \\ 
x_1+3x_2-x_3-x_4=9 \\ 
x_1+4x_2-4x_3+(7+a)x_4=16+a \\ 
x_1-2x_2+14x_3-11x_4=4
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I'm not asking for a straight answer to the solution, but more of a method for finding it :-)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of coefficients is: 
$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & -3 & 2 \\
 1 & 3 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 4 & -4 & 7+a \\
 1 & -2 & 14 & -11  
\end{pmatrix}$ Evaluate the determinant (A) of this matrix as a function of $a$.  All values of $a$ are allowed except when A$=0$.

In fact, the expression for A will be linear in $a$, so there is only one value of $a$ that is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you so much :-) I first tried to bring it to reduced row echelon form, but using the determinant of the matrix seems much easier. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so I calculated the determinant for the matrix to be 0 (a somewhat lengthy process), but how does that help me other than I now know that the matrix is not invertible? Thanks

Comment: The matrix should depend on $a$.  If it $0$ for all $a$ that means there is no solution for any a.  This would happen if the first,second, and fourth lines of the matrix were linearly dependent

Comment: .  I just checked - the coefficient for $(7+a)$ is $0$ - no dependence on $a$.  In that case it appears there is no solution for any $a$ since the determinant is zero.

Comment: If a matrix is not invertible, then there is no solution, since a solution requires multiplying the right hand side vector by the inverse matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. It means a lot to me :-)